Dropping a dimension in a list in R
I would like to combine 3 lists in R, each one obtained from a loop.
Each list contains one element, corresponding to a step of the lop, which in turn contains: i) an indentifier of the individual, b) a label of the timestamp and c) the multipolygon
Find below an example:

[[23]]
[[23]][[1]]
[1] "lobo"


[[23]][[2]]
[1] "2019_20"


[[23]][[3]]
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 422382.2 ymin: 4455098 xmax: 508882.2 ymax: 4511348
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N
2019_20                       geometry
1       1 MULTIPOLYGON (((452132.2 45...

I generate three main lists from loop: "a" with 20 elements, "b" with 10 elements and "d" with 40 elements. When I have my three lists, I tried to merge them into a new list with the "list" command:
new.list <- list(a, b, d)

My problem is that this new list has only 3 elements. I would like to have a single list with 70 elements, which then I could loop over to calculate overlap between the polygons of each temporal stamp. Basically I would need something similar to a dataframe to loop over, but I need a list as I am storing polygons. Any idea on how to do that?
Best,
Jacopo

Does this answer your question? How to combine two lists in R i.e. new.list <- c(a, b, d)

You'll get better and faster help if you share some sample/toy data (like dput(head(a)).
